# 407 Proxy Authentication Required - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/expo-cli

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have set the proxy using commands `npm config set proxy http://Username:Pwd@Proxy url:8080`.

And tried to install `npm install -g expo-cli`. I am facing the error like `407 Proxy Authentication Required - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/expo-cli` Please any one help me in this.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your username, password, host and port are correct, then try to do the command that way:

```
npm config set proxy http://"Username:Pwd"@Proxyurl:8080
```

notice the quotation mark around the username and password, and the removed space in your proxy url as well, doing so it should work now.